# How can i do my form submit without clicking with class instead of id

Tags: javascript, cart

I´m doing an e-commerce web and i want to the quantity section changes when you click out of the input, i did it, but the problem is i had used a js function with "getElementById" and it works but if i add more than 1 product the id only works in 1 form (obviusly), but when i use "getElementsByClassName"
nothings happens and chrome console say "Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...).submit is not a function at CantCartUpdate (cart.php:144:51) at HTMLInputElement.onblur (cart.php:110:139)" and i dont know what to do

part of my code:

```
<tbody>
              <?php
                for($i=0;$i<=count($myCart)-1;$i++){ 
                  if(isset($myCart[$i])){
                    if($myCart[$i]!=NULL){?>
              <tr>
                <td class="product-image">
                  <img src="<?php echo $myCart[$i]['imagen']?>" alt="<?php echo $myCart[$i]['nombre']?>">
                </td>
                <td class="product-name">
                  <h2 class="name"><?php echo $myCart[$i]['nombre']?></h2>
                </td>
                <td class="product-price"><h2 class="precio">$<?php echo number_format($myCart[$i]['precio'], 0, ',', '.')  ; ?></h2></td>
                <td class="product-quantity">
                    <form action="backend/cartActions.php" class="formCant" method="post">
                      <div class="cantidad">
                        <div class="cantidad-container">
                          <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $i; ?>">
                          <input type="number" class="nro updateCant" min="1" name="cantidad" onblur="CantCartUpdate()" value="<?php echo $myCart[$i]['cantidad'];?>">
                          <input type="submit"  class="sbm">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                </td>
```

js (it is in the same file):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function CantCartUpdate () {
  document.getElementsByClassName("formCant").submit();

}
```

Comment: The getElementsByClassName() method returns a collection of elements with a specified class name(s). [see here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp)

Comment: and what can i do because when a new product is added i get a new form equals to the other products form

Comment: if you want to simulate button click and you have only one button with this class, try this
`document.getElementsByClassName("formCant")[0].click();`

Comment: yep i know that but it only works at the first input, with the other nope because i use a for with php and every product i add it´ll be the same as others product

Comment: okay. you can add a click listener to every submit button and pass some data to it and receive in function to recognize. Something like
`<input type="submit" onclick="CantCartUpdate(<?php echo $myCart[$i]['cantidad'];?>)" class="sbm">`.

Comment: okay i´ll try it but what i should put on js CantCartUpdate()